# C# Change decibels (volume) in audio file

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm really new in NAudio and need your help. I'm working with NAudio and I need to change volume lvl in the audio file and write to a new file. I think I have to get samples of audio file and the increase `something` in them. But I don't know how to start. May anyone help me?
This is my code:

```
using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(inFile))
            {
                VolumeWaveProvider16 volumeProvider = new VolumeWaveProvider16(reader);
                using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outFile, reader.WaveFormat))
                {

                    while (true)
                    {
                        var frame = reader.ReadNextSampleFrame();
                        if (frame == null)
                            break;
                        //var a = frame[0];
                        writer.WriteSample(frame[0] + 0.2f);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Am I doing all right?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the PCM data, the simplest way is to increase each sample value by a constant.

Your example looks good. Have you tried comparing the old and the new WAV by listening to both?

A few things to note though:

- `ReadNextSampleFrame()` returns an *array* of floats with one value for each audio channel. If you have multi-channel audio you should iterate over the array with `foreach` and increase *each* value of the frame.
- Depending on the range of the retrieved sample values, adding 0.2 might have no effect. Have you checked what sort of values `ReadNextSampleFrame()` returns? I.e. when you debug your application, what are the actual values you are retrieving?  Are there some (or a lot) values bigger than 1?
- Since you do not know the range of your input values, you cannot clip them to that range. If a sample value is quite loud in the original file, increasing it might exceed the valid range which in turn might result in unexpected outputs.

Comment: Ok, I can get each sample (it's float value). What should I do next?

Comment: Basically just read each sample value from the buffer, increase it by 0.2 (assuming the range of the sample values is [0..1]), clip the boosted value to the valid range if necessary and then write the sample back into the buffer.